# ¿Cómo evolucionó fonéticamente "jínjol" desde "zizy̆phus"?

Tags: etimología, pronunciación

El **[jínjol](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MTlxXzd)**, también conocido como **[azufaifa](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4h0tXqz)** o **[yuyuba](http://dle.rae.es/?id=cEkru4X)**, es el fruto del **jinjolero** (*[Ziziphus jujuba](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziziphus_jujuba)*).

Por increíble que parezca, los tres nombres que he dado (así como otras muchas variantes, como *chínchol*, *jujube*...) provienen de la misma palabra persa زیزفون *zayzafûn*:

- persa: زیزفون *zayzafûn* -> griego: ζίζυφος *zízyphos* -> latín: *zizy̆phus* -> español: **jínjol**
- persa: زیزفون *zayzafûn* -> griego: ζίζυφον *zízyphon* -> arameo: *zūzfā* -> árabe hispánico: *azzufáyzafa* -> español: **azufaifa**
- persa: زیزفون *zayzafûn* -> griego: ζίζυφον *zízyphon* -> latín: *zizy̆phus* -> latín medieval: *jujuba* -> español: **yuyuba**

(Fuentes: [DLE](http://dle.rae.es/) y [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org)).

Pero por fascinante que esto sea, casi me sorprende más el poco parecido que hay entre *jínjol* y su origen latino, *zizy̆phus*: suponiendo que la palabra latina se pronuncie "cícifus", parece que se evoluciona de sonidos "Z-Z-F" a sonidos "J-N-J-L". ¿Es esto correcto?

**¿Cómo fue la transformación del latín *zizy̆phus* al español *jínjol*?** ¿Hay más ejemplos de palabras españolas que hayan sufrido cambios similares (mismos fonemas)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Habría que ver cómo fue la evolución real de esas palabras, ya que en el DLE figuran etimologías de tipo muy básico. Cuando se habla de latín no es lo mismo hablar de latín del siglo IV a. C. que del latín clásico del Imperio Romano temprano o del latín tardío, paso previo al romance. Es perfectamente posible que la palabra haya pasado varias veces del latín al castellano por vías diferentes.

También se cita un étimo en nominativo singular, *zizy̆phus*, que quizá (o probablemente) no haya sido la forma más habitual de aparición de la palabra en latín: de hecho nuestros sustantivos castellanos derivan generalmente de las formas acusativas de las palabras latinas, a veces, del plural reanalizado como singular (como en el caso de *bacteria*), otras veces con sufijos diminutivos, aumentativos (como en el caso de *corazón*), etc.

La *z* existía en latín pero fue suprimida y luego reincorporada al alfabeto para transcribir las palabras griegas con el sonido [dz]. Esta combinación de sonidos no existía en latín y difícilmente iba a tener una evolución fonética normal. Quizá frente a la vocal [i] se palatalizó en [dʒ]~[ʒ], confundiéndose más tarde con los resultados de cambios fonéticos de otros sonidos. Las palabras con [ʒ] en romance terminaron dando [x] en castellano moderno al perderse la sonoridad en las fricativas y [desplazarse la sibilante postalveolar a la posición velar](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reajuste_de_las_sibilantes_del_idioma_espa%C3%B1ol). Eso explicaría las *j* en castellano.

Por otra parte, en cierto punto de la evolución romance el sonido de la *yod* consonante ([j]) se reforzó como fricativa (de hecho hoy lo es, o incluso una africada, en casi todos los dialectos), y si se tomó prestada una palabra con [ʒ] en ese momento, este sonido pudo haberse fundido con aquél, lo cual explicaría *jujuba* > *yuyuba*.

En cuanto al sonido representado por *ph*, presumiblemente era una [f], que pudo muy bien haberse perdido, o bien haberse debilitado en [v]~[b]. En castellano se perdió la [f] inicial del latín, y el latín casi no tenía [f] salvo en esa posición, de manera que hoy casi todas las palabras castellanas con [f] son o fueron cultismos o préstamos, y la evolución de la [f] interna no fue normal (de hecho hay casos como latín *bubo* > latín vulgar *bufo* > castellano *búho*).

Esa enigmática *n* en *jínjol* no es tan extraña; aunque de manera arbitraria y esporádica, aparece un sonido [n] infijo en algunas palabras cuyos cognados latinos no lo tenían, como *macula* > *mancha*. Este agregado podría ser una forma de [alargamiento compensatorio](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alargamiento_compensatorio) aplicado a la sílaba, de manera de preservar su métrica (por evolución normal una palabra como [zizifus] en latín debió dar [zizfus] en algún punto, sincopando la [i] corta no acentuada, igual que [makula] > [makla]). En cualquier caso las nasales epentéticas no son raras en general: hay quien dice *trompezar* o *muncho*. Existe además la forma *jíjol*, sin nasal (este vegetal debe estar entre los que más nombres tiene en el mundo).

La parte final (*-ol*) no parece tener correlato con el latín original; ha de ser un simple sufijo. Quizá sea por influencia de palabras del mismo campo semántico como *fásol*, *fríjol*, *pésol*, etc. (el diminutivo latino *-ul-* dio *-ul-* en palabras cultas como *capítulo*, pero *-ol* en *[pésol](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SnkrHDf)* < *pisulum*).

La forma llana *yuyuba* debe haber experimentado un desplazamiento del acento antes de pasar al romance.

El cambio de vocales es de esperarse tratándose de una palabra tan expresiva. Ocurre algo parecido con el *ajonjolí* (sésamo): viene del árabe *al-ŷulŷulān* (*ŷ* = [dʒ]) y según Wikipedia se lo llama también *ajonjolín, ajonjulí, aljonjolé, aljonjolí, jonjolé, jonjolí, haholí, jijirí, ejonjilí*.